# How to enable FunctionName attribute on an azure function only if it is in a devvelopment environment?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, visual-studio-2022

I have an azure function written in C#. I want to enable a Http triggered Azure Function only if it is in a Development environment.

I tested this feature with using a pre-processor directive such as `#if` and i am able to show/hide an Azure function in the output window.

```
private const string HttpTestFn = "RunHttpTest";

#if DEBUG
        [FunctionName(HttpTestFn)]
#endif
```

However, i want to extend this to work based on the Environment such as

```
#if Environment.IsDevelopment()
    [FunctionName(HttpTestFn)]
#endif
```

How do i achieve this?

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work

```
#if Environment.IsDevelopment()
```

You would create a specific build configuration for the dev environment, when deploying to that environment, you use the build configuration to build, package and deploy to that environment
So you keep the

```
#if DEBUG
        [FunctionName(HttpTestFn)]
#endif
```

I am not sure what do you use to deploy your app to different environments, but will assume you are using some sort of a pipeline to build and deploy the app, so when building, you would use a different build parameters for development environment than for other.
For release you would use

```
dotnet build --configuration Release
```

but for your development environment you would use

```
dotnet build --configuration DEBUG
```

This way the version being deployed to dev won't have that function.

Another note, I would put the #if #endif at the start and end of the function file rather than just around the functionname attribute.

Comment: I do not have a separate file for the function. In this case, shall I wrap the whole function with `#if` & `#endif` ?

Comment: @blogs4t you can do. I would move it to another file on its own and do it there. I usually go for 1 function per file, unless it is a durable function.